# Issue matching backslash

Tags: regex

I'm searching a string something like this: `\u0026quot;3487 - IRA NEEDLES / PATH TO WESTMEADOW\u0026quot;`

Trying to match this: `3487 - IRA NEEDLES / PATH TO WESTMEADOW`

Using this regex: `/(\d\d\d\d\s-\s[A-za-z\s\/]+)/g`

But for some reason, it's matching the `\` and `u` after my intended match:

`3487 - IRA NEEDLES / PATH TO WESTMEADOW\u`

Could anyone help me out? I can't figure out what's wrong with the regex :/

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the regex implementation, but I think you only escaped the slash for the regex and not your programming languages. So try `\\/` instead of `\/`

Comment: I'm currently working in regex101, I'll be doing the actual stuff in javascript.`\\/` errors out :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your ranges is `A-z`. It contains backslash. You probably want `A-Z`.